# Prove: $x$ is a limit point iff there is a sequence that converges to $x$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove: $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a limit point of $A$ iff there is a sequence of points $\{x_{n}\}\subset A$ which are different from $x$ and converges to $x$

How should I start? in the $(\Rightarrow)$ I assume that I start with the definition of a limit point:

$x\in A$ is a limit point if for all $r>0$ $B(x,r)\cap A\setminus{x}\neq \emptyset$ and from there to get to the limit of a sequence and on $(\Leftarrow)$ to start with a sequence that converges and get to the definition of a limit point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x\in A$ be a limit point.  Then, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n \in B(x,1/n)\cap A\setminus x$ (by definition of limit point). From construction it is clear that $x_n\neq x$ and $x_n\in A$. We claim that $x_n \to x$. Indeed, since $x_n, x \in B(x,1/n)$ then $d(x_n,x)\leq 1/n$ for all $n$.

To prove the converse, let $\{x_n\}\subset A$ with $x_n\neq x$ converge to $x$. To show that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ let $r>0$ be arbitrary. We need to show that $B(x,r)\cap A\setminus x\neq \emptyset$. Indeed, by convergence of $x_n$ to $x$, there exists $n$ sufficiently large so that $d(x_n,x)<r$.  That is, $x_n \in B(x,r)\cap A\setminus x$, establishing the claim.

Comment: Can you show this without any metric space, i.e. without d(xn,x)? There may be no metric, without that how will you prove this theorem?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun ; you will have to use some metric, otherwise how will you define the convergence? $ (\mathbb{R}^n, L_2) $ can be used as example, where $L_2$ is the norm linear space suffix 2.